# Web page error with Internet Explorer 9 in Dynamic Workload Console

Tags: dynamic, console, workload-scheduler

I have problems with some panels in the Dynamic Workload Console using Explorer 9. Some pages are not displayed correctly and I receive the message: “object error”.

Comment: You need to provide samples, expected outcome.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to clean the cache of the browser and retry